# apply jquery plugin on vue json data

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using a vue component to fetch and show data as below:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [],
            post: {
                id: '',
                title: '',
                rating: '',
                ver: ''
            },
            pagination: {},
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchRecentPosts();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchRecentPosts() {
            fetch('api/recentposts')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.posts = res.data;
            })
        }
    },
}
```

I'm also using [rateYo](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/) plugin to show posts rating.
without using vue.js i'm able to turn my div attribute into star rating by :

```
$(".rateYo").each(function () {
  var rating = $(this).data("rating");
  $(this).rateYo({
      rating: rating,
      starWidth: "13px",
      spacing: "3px",
      ratedFill: "#ffb300",
      normalFill: "#d3d8e4",
      readOnly: true
  });
});
```

So, How should I apply it work on evey div inside a `v-for` loop using vue.js ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data() {
        return {
            posts: [
              {
                  id: 1,
                  title: 'Post One',
                  rating: 2.5
              },
              {
                  id: 2,
                  title: 'Post Two',
                  rating: 4.1
              }
            ],
            post: {
                id: '',
                title: '',
                rating: '',
                ver: ''
            },
            pagination: {},
        }
    },
    
    mounted() {
    
        $('.rateYo').each(function() {
        
            $(this).rateYo({
                rating: $(this).data('rating'),
                starWidth: "13px",
                spacing: "3px",
                ratedFill: "#ffb300",
                normalFill: "#d3d8e4",
                readOnly: true
            });
       
        });
    
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.3.2/jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.3.2/jquery.rateyo.min.css">

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(post,index) in posts" :key="index">
        <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
        <div class="rateYo" :data-rating="post.rating"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to put it inside muted() before.your code is not working for me either. I tried to alert something right after  `$('.rateYo').each(function() { ` not no luck. it seems because this blocks are rendering dynamically rateYo isn't working. But it works when using inside muted() on static divs

Comment: Finally I could make it work by adding the code inside `window.addEventListener('load', function () {` .Is it OK?

Comment: There are two options, Use a watcher or use a computed method to react to data changes. You would put the code found in mounted() inside one of these two solutions. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property
If you need help understanding how you can use one of these, i will update my answer but try to figure it out first.

Comment: @AliRezaei Without seeing the rest of your code, its difficult for anyone to actually give you an appropriate answer, it all depends on how you are doing your pagination., you want to execute the jQuery iteration upon the list being re-rendered.